# Why `new Array()` and `Array()` behaves the same in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Here is the examples

```
Array(1,2,3)
> [1,2,3]
new Array(1,2,3)
> [1,2,3]
Array(3)
> [undefined, undefined, undefined]
new Array(3)
> [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I saw some comments about "[never use Array with new](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript)". But I can't understand as I found `Array` and `new Array` seems to behave the same in Javascript.. Why do they behave the same? And why should one usage be preferred over the other?

I know `[]` literal syntax should usually be used instead of `Array`, I was just wondering what `Array` is..

**Is it a constructor function? If it is a constructor function, why could it be used without `new`?**

Comment: Actually neither `new Array()` nor `Array()` should be used. Use the literal syntax instead, i.e. `[1, 2, 3]`. Btw there is nothing in JavaScript from stopping you to call a constructor function without `new`.

Comment: care to share the comments you are mentioning so we know the context? :) I actually prefer the simple `[]` version :)

Comment: Don't use either `Array(1,2,3)` or `new Array(1,2,3)`. Always use `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @helpermethod I know `[]` is usually the best choice.. Just wondering what `Array` actually is..

Comment: Array are objects. You can access the key's value in object using the square bracket, same as Arrays.

Comment: I never really thought about it... @helpermethod do you care to explain why those should not be used?

Comment: @Salketer Because `new Array()` behaves in unexpected ways. E.g. `new Array(8)` initializes an 8 element array, whereas `new Array(8, 9)` initializes an array with the elements 8 and 9. `[8]` on the other hand gives you an array containing the element 1. Also `[]` is shorter.

Comment: @helpermethod fair enough, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When `Array` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initialises a new Array object. Thus the function call
>   `Array(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Array(…)`
>   with the same arguments.

http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.1

Comment: Nice! looked all over documentation, but you found it! :)